# qpdfview: Options "Pages Per Sheet" and "Page Set" cannot be used together. Please turn one of those options off

Tags: ubuntu, pdf, printing, printer

I have a PDF file (with 8 pages), I want to print it in the following way:

- It must be 4 pages per sheet,
- The odd pages must be printed together, same for the even pages

So, we have these pages (1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 8) that must be printed in one paper (both sides).

The odd pages must be printed as shown below:

```
 +-------+-------+
 |       |       |
 |   1   |   3   |
 |_______|_______|
 |       |       |
 |   5   |   7   |
 |       |       |
 +-------+-------+
```

The even pages must be printed (in the back of the paper) as shown below:

```
 +-------+-------+
 |       |       |
 |   4   |   2   |
 |_______|_______|
 |       |       |
 |   8   |   6   |
 |       |       |
 +-------+-------+
```

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, and qpdfview software to view and print the pdf file. I got the following message: ***Options "Pages Per Sheet" and "Page Set" cannot be used together. Please turn one of those options off.***

Is there any solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to split the PDF file into 2 separate files: odd pages in the 1st file, and the even pages in the 2nd file. Then, I printed each one.

I used `pdftk`, and below the codes that I used:

```
pdftk A=BigFile.pdf cat Aodd output odd.pdf
pdftk A=BigFile.pdf cat Aeven output even.pdf
```